# Got error Msg 208 while merge multiple record in a single record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

A query in SQL Server fetches around 30 records with 15 columns. I want to merge it and convert it into one record with 30*15 = 450 columns in a single records. But when I try to declare `@SqlText` variable at start.

Here is the sample code:

```
DECLARE @SqlText NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @SqlText NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'select * from ((SELECT 'abc' AS ID,  
                            SUBSTRING(col1,0,10) ID_Mark,
                            CASE 
                              WHEN (UPPER(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(col2, '0123456789', NULL ), 0, 2 ))='E-')
                                   THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(col2, '0123456789', NULL ), 3, 4 ) .......
                                  group by ID, ID_Mark, col1, col2, .....)) PE'
SELECT @SqlText  = @SqlText  + ' INNER JOIN PE'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, ID) +'.ID_Mark =  ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ID_Mark) 
FROM PE 
order by ID_Mark

SET @SqlText  = @SqlText  
EXEC (@SqlText)
```

When I execute this code, I get an error

> Msg 208 
>   Invalid Object name 'PE'.

Where PE is the table alias name of the query. How to resolve this type of issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the Error message because, in the Query string, you are giving the Single Quotes wrong. If you want to have a single quote inside a Query string, then you should specify it as 2 single quotes.

So If you want to select the string 'ABC' inside a Query string, You should give it like this

```
EXEC('SELECT ''ABC'' AS MyStr')
```

So Your query needs to be changed like this

```
DECLARE @SqlText NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'select * from ((SELECT ''abc'' AS ID,  
                            SUBSTRING(col1,0,10) ID_Mark,
                            CASE 
                              WHEN (UPPER(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(col2, ''0123456789'', NULL ), 0, 2 ))=''E-'')
                                   THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(col2, ''0123456789'', NULL ), 3, 4 ) .......
                                  group by ID, ID_Mark, col1, col2, .....)) PE'
SELECT @SqlText  = @SqlText  + ' INNER JOIN PE'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, ID) +'.ID_Mark =  ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ID_Mark) 
FROM PE 
order by ID_Mark

SET @SqlText  = @SqlText  
EXEC (@SqlText)
```

Just replace each Sinlge Quotes with 2 single quotes.

Comment: when i replace single quotes with double then after i got an error Msg 135, @SqlText has been already defined. Variable name must be unique in a query batch.

Comment: You have declared the variable  @SqlText twice, remove the 1st declaration and try. Please check the updated answer

Comment: Yeah i try again then i got 'Invalid Object Name PE'

Comment: That's because you don't have a table or view in your database with the name PE.

Comment: if you want PE as an alias name for a table then use it like TableName as PE

Comment: But i got the PE alias name from SQL query which is declare inside the @SqlText variable not as table name As PE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162316/discussion-between-jayasurya-satheesh-and-user8487380).